# Найти в файле самую редкую букву (буква которая встречается меньше всего в тексте)

Tags: python, find, counter, min

```py
from collections import Counter

inp = 'zen.txt'
letters = 0
words = 0
lines = 0

for line in open(inp):
    lines += 1
    letters += len(line)

    pos = 'out'
    for letter in line:
        if letter != ' ' and pos == 'out':
            words += 1
            pos = 'in'
        elif letter == ' ':
            pos = 'out'

rare_letter = Counter(str(letters))
rare_letter = min(rare_letter, key=rare_letter.get)


print(f'Количество букв в файле: {letters}')
print(f'Количество слов в файле: {words}')
print(f'Количество строк в файле: {lines}')
print(f'Наиболее редкая буква: {rare_letter}')
```

Помогите разобраться. Не могу добиться правильного результата о поиске наиболее редкой буквы в тексте. `inp = 'zen.txt'` входные данные - текстовый документ с текстом.

Comment: Вообще не понятно что вы тут считаете. У вас в letters суммируются длины всех строк, но не текст из строк. Получается вы считаете общую длину текста, потом это число переводите в строку и считаете какие цифры в этом числе встречаются.

Comment: а если ```rare_letter = Counter(inp)``` он не понимает что нужно в файл смотреть

Comment: Нужно открыть файл, прочитать из него текст, потом положить этот текст в Counter: `with open(inp) as file: counter = Counter(file.read())` . Правда так и пробелы с переносами строк посчитает, но это уже другая проблема.

Comment: все правильно вы сказали :) выводит ! знак. я думал дернуть из ```letters``` так как там уже прошел фильтр и собраны только все буквы

Comment: Как у вас в letters буквы могут быть, если изначально там число 0, а потом туда прибавляется длина (len) каждой строки, в итоге там число. Это не фильтрация символов, это суммирование длин строк.

Comment: уже осознал свою ошибку(с вашей подсказкой), спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему не ищется самая редкая буква? Вы берёте переменную `letters`, которая содержит число (а не символы) и метод `Counter` ищет самую редкую цифру из этого числа. Благодаря подсказке @insolor я подправил ваш код.

```
for line in open(inp):
    lines += 1
    letters += len(line)
    words += len(line.split()) # Упрощённый подсчёт слов

with open(inp) as file:
    counter = Counter(file.read())  # Самая редкая буква учитывая регистр
    # counter = Counter(file.read().lower()) # Без учёта регистра
rare_letter = min(counter, key=counter.get)
```

Comment: спасибо, и код лучше ) ```min(counter, key=counter.get)``` так же думал об этом, не смог прикрутить