# Поиск самой редкой буквы в питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

```
letters = 0
words = 0
lines = 0
 
for line in open('zen.txt'):
    words += len(line.split())
    letters += sum(map(str.isalpha, line))
    lines += 1
 
print('Количество букв в файле:', letters)
print('Количество слов в файле:', words)
print('Количество строк в файле:', lines)
```

Помогите дописать код который найдет самую редкую букву в тексте и не будет учитывать спец символы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно считать буквы и на этой основе найти самую редкую.

Например, это удобно сделать через [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Пример:

```
from collections import Counter

letters = 0
words = 0
lines = 0
letter_by_counter = Counter()
 
for line in open('zen.txt'):
    words += len(line.split())
    letters += sum(map(str.isalpha, line))
    letter_by_counter.update(c for c in line if c.isalpha())
    lines += 1
 
print('Количество букв в файле:', letters)
print('Количество слов в файле:', words)
print('Количество строк в файле:', lines)

rare_letter = min(letter_by_counter, key=letter_by_counter.get)
print('Самая редкая буква:', rare_letter)
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно в этом способе убрать учёт регистра букв, например чтобы все к нижнему были переведены.

Comment: [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1398276/1365) еще был интересный вариант получения самой редкой буквы из Counter: `rare_letter = min(counter, key=counter.get)`

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, интересно выглядит, нужно поразбираться как это работает :) UPD. А, понятно, итерация словаря это ключи, но нам нужно найти по значениям, поэтому ключом функции будет `get`, так получаем ключ с минимальным значением :)

Comment: В этом варианте буквы B и b являются разными буквами

Comment: @xFox, а надо чтобы регистр не учитывался? Тогда приводите к одному регистру, например `letter_by_counter.update(c.upper() for c in line if c.isalpha())`

Comment: @gil9red, большое спасибо! Всё работает!

Comment: @xFox, пожалуйста :)